Spring Boot Kafka Micrometer observability doesn't work with concurrency enabled
I configured my application to load beans based on properties in this way:
        @Bean
        @ConditionalOnProperty(
            prefix = "fleexi.kafka.override-concurrency",
            value = {"enabled"}
        )
        ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> kafkaListenerContainerFactoryWithConcurrency(ConsumerFactory<String, String> kafkaConsumerFactory, FleexiKafkaProperties fleexiKafkaProperties) {
            ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory();
            factory.setConcurrency(fleexiKafkaProperties.getOverrideConcurrency().getListenerConcurrency());
            factory.getContainerProperties().setObservationEnabled(true);
            factory.setConsumerFactory(kafkaConsumerFactory);
            return factory;
        }

        @Bean
        @ConditionalOnMissingBean({ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory.class})
        ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> kafkaListenerContainerFactory(ConsumerFactory<String, String> kafkaConsumerFactory) {
            ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory();
            factory.getContainerProperties().setObservationEnabled(true);
            factory.setConsumerFactory(kafkaConsumerFactory);
            return factory;
        }

In the first case, with concurrency enabled observabilities log traceId and spanId doesn't work.

In second case, without concurrency it works properly

Concurrency breaks observability?
EDIT:
The example here:
https://github.com/claudiomerli/demo-issue-spring-kafka-3459

As Soby asked on GitHub, please, provide a simple project to reproduce on our side.

https://github.com/claudiomerli/demo-issue-spring-kafka-3459

Your problem is here:
 ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> kafkaListenerContainerFactoryWithConcurrency(

where the default containerFactory for the @KafkaListener is indeed that kafkaListenerContainerFactory.
So, since your custom kafkaListenerContainerFactoryWithConcurrency is out of use, that is not a surprise that traces are not logged.
Try just this configuration properties instead of those beans:
spring.kafka.consumer.group-id=TEST
spring.kafka.listener.concurrency=10
spring.kafka.listener.observation-enabled=true

UPDATE
Since you cannot rely on the auto-configuration and have to use those conditional beans you can trick it like this:
    @Bean("kafkaListenerContainerFactory")
    @ConditionalOnProperty(
        prefix = "fleexi.kafka.override-concurrency",
        value = {"enabled"}
    )
    ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> kafkaListenerContainerFactoryWithConcurrency(ConsumerFactory<String, String> kafkaConsumerFactory, FleexiKafkaProperties fleexiKafkaProperties) {

With that default factory bean name expected by the @KafkaListener.

I cannot use properties beacuse that configuration, in my project, resides in a common library shared in all microservices.
Also if you notice, in the demo project, if the kafkaListenerContainerFactory comes into play everything works.
it doesn't work only if I set the concurrency

If ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory is out of use which one I can use to make a programmatic configuration for this setup?

Can you please provide me a way to do that?

Sorry, I might not been clear. The @KafkaListener expects a bean for the ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory exactly with the name kafkaListenerContainerFactory by default. Since you use a kafkaListenerContainerFactoryWithConcurrency bean name and don't use it in your @KafkaListener , that's what I meant with an out of use. You might consider to use a name attribute of the @Bean annotation instead.

See an UPDATE in my answer.

Adding
@Bean("kafkaListenerContainerFactory")

on both bean declaration it worked.
You can see it on the example.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
